# How to pass strings and commands from parent component to child component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I use Prism as the MVVM container for WPF, and I want to define a series of commands in the parent component, and then let the child component execute different commands.

How can I write to be successful?

```xml
// parent  control

<StackPanel>
    <local:TestUserControl1 xxx="hello" yyy="TestJumpOtherTabCommand"></local:TestUserControl1>

    <local:TestUserControl1  xxx="world" yyy="TestModifyModelDtoCommand"></local:TestUserControl1>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
// vm
public DelegateCommand TestJumpOtherTabCommand { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand TestModifyModelDtoCommand { get; set; }
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="GearboxManagementSystem.Views.TestUserControl1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="xxx"></TextBlock>
        <Button Command="yyy"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: My Code Snip1]

[image: My Code Snip2]

Comment: If you did everything correctly, then your ViewModel should be in the Data Context of the Window.
And almost always nested UI elements inherit the Data Context from the parent container.
Therefore, if implemented correctly, you should have a Window ViewModel in the UserControl's Data Context.
And there shouldn't be any problems with binding to its commands.
If there are problems, then it is impossible to determine their cause from your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

When designing custom user controls, you can define dependency properties. Go to the code-behind of the control and add the code below. I define a `Text` dependency property for the text that you want to bind in the `TextBlock` and a `Command` dependency property for the `Button`.

```
public partial class TestUserControl1 : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(TestUserControl1));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TestUserControl1));

   public TestUserControl1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public string Text
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
      set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
   }

   public ICommand Command
   {
      get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
      set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
   }
}
```

In your user control XAML, please add columns or rows, because as it is the `TextBlock` and the `Button` will overlap in the same cell of the `Grid` (only one is visible, the other one is occluded). Furthermore, add bindings that use [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0) with an [`AncestorType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype?view=net-5.0) of your custom control. This will bind the target property to the dependency property defined in your user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.TestUserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TestUserControl1}}}"/>
      <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TestUserControl1}}}"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, set or bind the dependency properties of your user control in the parent control.

```
<StackPanel>
   <local:TestUserControl1 Text="Hello" Command="{Binding TestJumpOtherTabCommand}"/>
   <local:TestUserControl1  Text="World" Command="{Binding TestModifyModelDtoCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here are valuable resources that you should read before continuing to implement your own control. They will provide the basics on what dependency properties are and how to define or use them.

- [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How to: Implement a Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Don't over complicate the solution.
The main function of the UserControl is to represent the Data Context.
And, first of all, it is necessary to ensure its correct transmission.
Adding additional DependentcyProperty is better for some kind of visual effects (interaction within the View).

Comment: ohhhhhh！ Thank you very much. So it can be realized.